# Use Sherlock Sample code for Actionbar + Tab fragments?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am working on an Application in which I have to use the Action below 3.0 also. So I am using Sherlock Library for this.

But its getting very tough to use this library as I am unable to catch few important events like I want to use the ActionBar & TabFragments on my screen for which I have edited the code and used it like:

```
public class TabNavigation extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private TextView mSelected;
    ActionMode mModes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
        mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        mModes = startActionMode(new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions());

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        mSelected.setText("Selected: " + tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }


    private final class AnActionModeOfEpicProportions implements ActionMode.Callback {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
            boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

            menu.add("Save")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_compose_inverse : R.drawable.ic_compose)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.ic_search)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            menu.add("Refresh")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_refresh_inverse : R.drawable.ic_refresh)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            menu.add("Save")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_compose_inverse : R.drawable.ic_compose)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.ic_search)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            menu.add("Refresh")
            .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_refresh_inverse : R.drawable.ic_refresh)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(TabNavigation.this, "Got click: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //mode.finish();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mModes!=null){
            mModes = startActionMode(new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions());
        }
    }

}
```

In which `mModes = startActionMode(new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions());` is the code which will provide the ActionBar. but how can I control the backKey press for this Actionbar class. Please suggest me.

Also I want to change the image provide on ActionBar. I am sorry but I have searched alot but didn't got the image click listener event in the code. 
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In which mModes = startActionMode(new
>   AnActionModeOfEpicProportions()); is the code which will provide the
>   ActionBar. but how can I control the backKey press for this Actionbar
>   class. Please suggest me.

`startActionMode` doesn't *"provide the ActionBar"* it starts the contextual action bar which is different from the standard `ActionBar`. You most likely don't need to observe the BACK button for the contextual action bar, but you do have a callback, because the BACK button will trigger the contextual action bar to be closed so `onDestroyActionMode` will be called. If you still want to look after the BACK button then implement a watch in the `onBackPressed` callback to see if it's called while the contextual action bar is currently showing.

> Also I want to change the image provide on ActionBar.

For the standard `ActionBar` there are a lot of tutorials/samples/documentation on how to change its look. For the contextual action bar you also have options to change its appearance with a custom theme(for example, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338289/contextual-actionbar-styles)).

> I am sorry but I have searched alot but didn't got the image click
>   listener event in the code

Doesn't make sense, explain better what you're looking for.