# Android Contextual Action Bar Styling

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how to get this divider shown in the Contextual Action Bar between the check and the title styled as shown in the image below.  The previous developer removed that divider and I would like to have it back.  Any direction would be very helpful.  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338289/contextual-actionbar-styles

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle" style in your theme. Something like the following:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">
  @style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode
</item>
```

See this thread: [Contextual Action Bar: Done button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281509/contextual-action-bar-done-button)