# Contextual Action Bar: Done button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

Is there a way to customize the image or at least the color of the "done" button in the top corner left of the picture below ?

[image: Contextual Action Bar]
BTW, I'm using ABS to handle my actionbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `attrs.xml` in `ActionBarSherlock`'s source code you will see these attributes:

```
    <!-- =================== -->
    <!-- Action mode styles  -->
    <!-- =================== -->
    <eat-comment />
    <attr name="actionModeStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle" format="reference" />
    <!-- Background drawable to use for action mode UI -->
    <attr name="actionModeBackground" format="reference" />
    <!-- Background drawable to use for action mode UI in the lower split bar -->
    <attr name="actionModeSplitBackground" format="reference" />
    <!-- Drawable to use for the close action mode button -->
    <attr name="actionModeCloseDrawable" format="reference" />
    <!-- Drawable to use for the Share action button in WebView selection action modes -->
    <attr name="actionModeShareDrawable" format="reference" />
```

You can use `actionModeCloseDrawable` in your `styles.xml` on your theme with the image you want to add.

Comment: I was searching in the styles file instead of the theme. Thx!