# How to change the Font of the Contextual Actionbar.?

Tags: java, android, typeface

I have a contextual action bar which is showing some text. I have changed the font of each and every text in my App expect this cab. I looked for it, but I am unable to find any. Is there any way to change the font of CAB to an external typeface font.?

Here is what I have:

[image]

Here is the font I want:

[image]

The font is external one, called VTKS-BAGACO.ttf

Comment: Oh my god that is unreadable.

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11277115/321697

Comment: @kcoppock Actually I have another font to use which is not very different from the default Android font. So I am using this one right now so that I can easily understand all those who have changed.

Comment: @kcoppock I read that, but that is giving error in my code, at layout inflater. Can you please give an example code for that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create external typeface for  VTKS-BAGACO. and put it in assets folder.
Now use that typeface as below in your activity:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "VTKS-BAGACO.otf");
textview.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type SingleSelectActionModeCallback.

This error is what I am getting When I am entering this:
TextView tv= (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.menu.advanced_delegations_multiselect, null);
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "VTKS-BAGACO.otf");
tv.setTypeface(tf);

Comment: Nad by the way what is this textview.?

Comment: it's your Action bar text, Which you want to change.

Comment: But its menu and the shown text is menuitem, not textview