# How to customize actionbar action buttons only

Tags: android

I would like to style the action buttons for the context action bar only, my current style applies to all action buttons not just the CAB buttons. Help would be much appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>

<style name="myActionButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contextual Actionbar styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338289/contextual-actionbar-styles)

Comment: I want to style a non-standard android:actionMode button not one of these Close, Cut, Copy, Paste ect. How would I achive that?