# How can i add dividers to split action bar

Tags: android, divider, splitactionbar

I researched a lot of time in google this theme but my split action bar still without dividers. I try to use options

`<item name="android:showDividers">beginning</item>
 <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
 <item name="android:divider">@color/grey</item>`

or

`<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@android:drawable/my_divider</item>`

to  app theme  or actionBar style.

On [developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) i found nothing too.
How can i add divider?

Comment: have a look on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338289/contextual-actionbar-styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **view** widget as an alternative to actionbar divider.

```
<View 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="#000000" />
```

Comment: @Prag's that seems to be the solution. Why don't you answer it then.