# Is there a way to change the background color for contextual actionbar?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have implemented a Contextual `ActionBar`, however i would like it it's background to match the `ActionBar`. Is there a way of changing the background of the Contextual `ActionBar`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338289/contextual-actionbar-styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
   actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#90DED5")));
```